# Error executing SQL Server CLR "hello world"

Tags: sql-server, clr

When running this sample

```
CREATE TYPE LocationTableType AS TABLE 
    ( LocationName VARCHAR(50)
    , CostRate INT )
GO
```

from SQl Manager (SQL Server 9) I get this error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

sp_configure 'clr enabled' is already set to 1 and the service was restarted.

What went wrong?

Thanks,
P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (SQL Server 9)

User-defined **table** types are a feature introduced in SQL Server 2008, version 10.

[`CREATE TYPE` in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

[`CREATE TYPE` in SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)